# Hana express edition suddenly stopped accepting connection requests

Tags: hana

I have been using Hana 2.0 Express Edition for a few months now, I have it installed in VMWare on Windows 10 and **it worked perfectly until today.** I double checked everything again and it seems fine, I don't know what else to check. If I run a select in the server itself, that works. If I ping the IP address (I had set a static IP address in the VM) from Windows that works as well. I don't see any error messages on startup, and when I run `HDB info` I see the four processes. It fails with timeout error when I try to connect with JDBC or from the Eclipse plugin. What else should I look at? The port numbers didn't change. Also, I didn't install any new software in my system.

[image]
[image]

VMware adapters:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post *what* processes you see as active with `HDB info`.

Comment: Please see the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the IP address of the VM to the same subnet as the network adapter did the trick. The network adapter IP address was changed automatically by Windows when I tried to fix an unrelated Internet problem in the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Can you log in directly from the VM? In the console, use

```
hdbsql -i 90 -d SYSTEMDB
```

What do the latest files called daemon*.trc  and nameserver*.trc in directory /usr/sap/HXE/HDB90/hxehost/trace say?

Also, how's the space on disk? ( du -h )

PS: You can ignore the UUID message in the RFC trace.

Comment: Lucia, yes, I can login in the console and run a select. Problem is with Windows client connections. I deleted all the `.trc` files and rerun Hana. I couldn't find anything wrong in the files. With regard to space, I created the VM with the defaults and Hana starts without complaining. Anything in particular to search in the trace files?

Comment: Since there are no evident errors in the traces, it may be the case that Hana never receives anything from the Windows clients. I tried deactivating the Windows firewall but got the same timeout error. I checked the VM network adapters and they are active. I'm running out of ideas, any hint will be welcome.

Comment: I found the problem, ping is not working, please take a look at the adapters screenshot I added to the question

Comment: Are your VM settings to NAT or Bridge? It looks like you should be using Bridged. DHCP seems to be assigning the guest an IP but the VM is showing the one assigned to the host.

Comment: I'm not using NAT or Bridge, I'm using Host-only with a static IP

Comment: So if the IP you set statically does not match the IP you're getting from DHCP (they are not even in the same range) it makes sense you cannot reach the VM from outside.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I fix this? I guess I need to change the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot the `hdbnameserver` process is the only process capable of answering client requests and that only for the `SystemDB`. HANA express edition comes as a multi-tenant installation with the *default tenant* DB `HXE`.

To connect to the `HXE` database, you need to start it first. Once started a `hdbindexserver` process will be visible in the `HDB info` list.

To start the database, login to the `SystemDB` and execute `ALTER SYSTEM START DATABASE hxe`.

Once started, you should be able to connect to `HXE` again.

In order to find out about the cause for `HXE` to be stopped, I recommend checking the indexserver trace files.

Comment: Lars, I started the database, I can see `hdbindexserver` in the `HDB info` list, but the problem persists. By the way, I cannot connect to ANY database from a client application, including SYSTEMDB.

Comment: Please take a look at the second screenshot taken from `dev_rfc.trc`

Comment: The dev_rfc.trc file doesn’t help here, as it is not related to the session handling. Have you checked the indexserver and/or nameserver trace files? Also, have you tried to connect to the SystemDB locally via `hdbsql`?

Comment: I checked the traces and couldn't find much. I can connect locally with no issues; the problem happens when I try to connect from a Windows client, either with JDBC or from the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Have you checked whether you are still able to connect to the virtual machine via network? E.g. via `ssh`? From your description I figure that the virtual machine network connection might not be reachable any longer. Also check whether the IP address of the VM guest has changed.

Comment: I checked the IP address and it didn't change, I also ping it from Windows and that works. I have a static IP address in the VM configured as `host-only`. I also tried deactivating the firewall in Windows, but that didn't help.

Comment: Ok, so the network connection works, but HANA doesn’t react to the logon request. Have you maybe changed the `listeninterface` so that the instance is actually not listening to the network adapter used to communicate with the host-only network?

Comment: My bad, ping is **not** working and that's the problem. I ping the IP address displayed in `sbin/ifconfig` and get a timeout. The network adapters are active, the `hosts` file is correct and the configuration in the VM is `host-only`, I also deactivated the firewall, what else can I check?

Comment: I added a picture of the adapters configuration and ifconfig, I cannot tell if it's correct and cannot find information online.